# Python OOP challenge, problem with object and method

Tags: loops, oop, fundamentals-ts

```
 class Song:
     def __init__(self, title, artist):
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist


    def how_many(self, listener):
        print(listener) 
    


obj_1 = Song("Mount Moose", "The Snazzy Moose")
obj_1.how_many(['John', 'Fred', 'Bob', 'Carl', 'RyAn'])
obj_1.how_many(['Luke', 'AmAndA', 'JoHn']) here
```

#the listener contains 2 lists inside, anything I do produces two lists, is there a way to
separate the list inside the listener without changing the objects calling the how_many
method simultaneously.
Thank you!!! in advance

Comment: Could you provide a desired output?

Comment: I must count the first wave of listener which is 5, then the second wave which is 3 without counting John again since he's already in wave 1

Comment: so I should return 5 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'm not sure the input `JoHn` in second wave is a typo or you need to capitalize all input. I assume you need capitalize it.
- You can use `set` to deal with the remove the duplicate in mutiple input.

#### example code:

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, title, artist):
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.linstener = set()

    def how_many(self, listener):
        listener = [ele.capitalize() for ele in listener]
        print(len((self.linstener | set(listener)) ^ self.linstener))
        self.linstener.update(listener)
        # print(listener) 

obj_1 = Song("Mount Moose", "The Snazzy Moose")
obj_1.how_many(['John', 'Fred', 'Bob', 'Carl', 'RyAn'])
obj_1.how_many(['Luke', 'AmAndA', 'JoHn'])
```

#### result:

```
5
2
```

Comment: damn, it was too complicated for me to understand, but thanks man! I'll dissect it and try to analyze how it works!

Comment: @NewCoder if this solution too complicated for you, I could provide a simpler solution. Or you can try to learn `set` ,`|`(something like plus) and `^`(like minus).

Comment: no, I think it's perfect, I'll analyze it so I  can learn something from it. :'D sorry I'm just starting.